# Jquery - Cycle Through Spans, Assigning Width From Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

Is there a way to cycle through spans and assign each one an array value.

For example:

I have an array that contains the values [45,50,106]. Is there a way to cycle through when hovering over and applying a span one of the array values. So the first span it comes across gets given the width 45. The second span that it comes across gets given the value 50 and so on?

```
// Multi-Expanding Icon Version:      
var widths = [];
$("ul#navigation-three").children('li').children('span:nth-child(2)').each(function(){
    widths.push($(this).width());
});

$('ul#navigation-three').hoverIntent(function () {    
    // Assign each span:nth-child(2) with the widths from the array in order
},

function () 
});
```

Comment: To be clear - the first hover over a span gives it the first array value, the second hover over a span (any span? including the original?) gets the second width and so on? What about the 4th span when there are only 3 values in the array?

Comment: Something like this but this doesn't work but shows the idea a bit better I think:

`i = 0;
  
  $("ul#navigation-three > li").children('span:nth-child(2)').each(function(){
   $(this).animate({"width":+widths[i]+"px"}, 0);
   i = i++;
  });`

So each time it finds a span:nth-child it makes the width the next number in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, I assume you mean something like:

```
var widths=[10,20,30];
$("ul#navigation-three > li").children('span:nth-child(2)').each(function(index){
       $(this).animate({"width":+widths[index]+"px"}, 0); 
});
```

I used the index parameter given the the `each()` function

Comment: Beautiful! Exactly what I needed. I wasn't too far off then :P

Comment: Just a matter of knowing the syntax :) Glad I could help